# Split PDF page to multiple page in C#

Tags: c#, pdf, split

I'm creating an application for Windows 8.1 in C#. Into Windows.Data.Pdf i've found how use PDF files in my application. But i want to know if i can split one A3 page to multiple PDF files ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to split a page, you want to tile it.

This is explained in [Chapter 6 of my book](http://manning.com/lowagie2/samplechapter6.pdf) (section 6.2.3). Take a look at the `TilingHero` example ([Java](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=116) / [C#](http://sourceforge.net/p/itextsharp/code/HEAD/tree/book/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextInAction2Ed/Chapter06/TilingHero.cs)). In this example, one large page ([hero.pdf](http://examples.itextpdf.com/resources/pdfs/hero.pdf)) is split into a PDF with several A4 pages ([superman.pdf](http://examples.itextpdf.com/results/part2/chapter06/superman.pdf)).

[image]

This is some code:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(resource);
Rectangle pagesize = reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1); 
using (Document document = new Document(pagesize)) {
    // step 2
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, ms);
    // step 3
    document.Open();
    // step 4
    PdfContentByte content = writer.DirectContent;
    PdfImportedPage page = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, 1);
    // adding the same page 16 times with a different offset
    float x, y;
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        x = -pagesize.Width * (i % 4);
        y = pagesize.Height * (i / 4 - 3);
        content.AddTemplate(page, 4, 0, 0, 4, x, y);
        document.NewPage();
     }
}
```

The math is valid for an A0 page. You need to adapt it for an A3 page (meaning: the math you need is way easier to do).

You need to calculate `pagesize` so that it results in smaller pages, and then use something like this:

```
using (Document document = new Document(pagesize)) {
    // step 2
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, ms);
    // step 3
    document.Open();
    // step 4
    PdfContentByte content = writer.DirectContent;
    PdfImportedPage page = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, 1);
    // adding the same page 16 times with a different offset
    float x, y;
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        x = -pagesize.Width * (i % 4);
        y = pagesize.Height * (i / 4 - 3);
        content.AddTemplate(page, x, y); // we don't scale anymore
        document.NewPage();
     }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain me your math ? because I need to split all formats of pages in any other

Comment: It's math, I can't explain it in words. It is already explained in code, isn't it? It doesn't require any math that goes beyond what is taught in high school.

Comment: Ok but with this method, the page size is always A0 is it normal ?

Comment: In my example, page size doesn't matter. I never mention page sizes, I just divide the page in 16 equal pages preserving the aspect-ratio. Are you saying that you are unable to do simple divisions?

Comment: i'm not saying that but i want to split A0 pdf page into veritable A4 pages but in your example the page format isn't resize

Comment: ??? What do you mean? You say: I have a single A3 file and I want to split it into multiple PDF files. I explain how to tile a PDF with a single large page into a PDF with multiple smaller pages. If you *burst* this PDF, you have split the single PDF with a large page into several PDFs with smaller pages. If that's not what you meant, I suggest that you rephrase your question. Your claim that the pages in my example are not smaller than A0 is wrong.

Comment: So, i want to tile a PDF page into smaller PDF pages. For example, i have one A0, A1, A2, or A3 plan, I want to tile it into A4 page to read the plan on tablet be easier. Do you understand me ?

Comment: http://examples.itextpdf.com/resources/pdfs/hero.pdf is a PDF document with an A0 page. http://examples.itextpdf.com/results/part2/chapter06/superman.pdf is a PDF document with 16 A4 pages that, if you glued them together would be an A0 file. That is what tiling is about. Yet you claim that this isn't true. I don't understand why you think that the 16 pages in the resulting file aren't A4 pages.

Comment: Because when i execute your method in my code the format of 16 pages are 841 x 1189 and not 210 x 297

Comment: Now I see what is causing the confusion. The original example converts an A4 file into 16 A4 files by rescaling the original image. It goes without saying that you don't need to rescale the page.

Comment: See the updated answer: you need to calculate a new page size and you shouldn't scale the `page`. As I said: this is elementary math.

Comment: What's the math to convert A0 into A3 ? Because i'm searching since this morning and i still have not found

Comment: A0 is double the size of A1, but rotated. A1 is double the size of A2, but rotated. A2 is double the size of A3, but rotated. So... A0 is 8 times the size of A3, but rotated. (Rotated means: switch the values of height and width.)